# Confused about moderators decisions about flags

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

Earlier, I got the yellow icon in top bar indicating a flag to be review. It showed me a flag about [an answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22669/how-can-i-measure-and-log-the-amount-of-radiation-while-being-on-a-plane/22671#22671), the flag was "not an answer", I got the option to either confirm the flag, or flag it as something else, or to mark the flag itself as an invalid flag. I think that answer was fine so I rejected the flag and marked it as invalid flag. This action by me will create a new flag but not to the answer, instead a flag to the flag. So far everything is ok.

The confusion starts here, now the moderator got two flags, one from the other user who flagged the answer as "not answer" and one flag from me to that flag. Logic says the moderator must approve one and deny one, either the first flag is correct and the answer is "not an answer" or my flag is correct and the first flag is invalid and the answer is fine. The problem is, the moderator did not accept the first flag because the answer still there, and at the same time he refused my flag to the first flag! This way the moderator is contradicting himself! Because he says the answer is fine but at the same time he rejected my flag which goes along with his decision! Confusion confusion.

Now, can a moderator explain this, please? Am I missing something? Or can you please accept my flag, I have hats to collect my dear!

Comment: Have you seen [this question on flagging as invalid on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112392/am-i-using-the-invalid-flag-flag-wrongly)? I believe it explains how the system "works" (which many people find confusing for the reason you describe!)

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks mate, now I can die in peace.

Comment: Just for the record, this system is weird. I don't like it.

Comment: Nor do I! But the place for that debate is Meta.SO not here, as it's a StackExchange wide behaviour. (You'll have to wait for another flag to get your badge, sorry!)

Comment: I post it here because I though it is a human error (mods are human I suppose ;) didn't know it is an SE wide behavior. Now things are clear for the next generations :)

Comment: Again, for the record, it says disputed, not declined. So our mode still the best.

Answer (score 8):

After reading the post in MSO which was suggested by gagravarr, here is a simple explanation:

**When you flag a flag as an `invalid flag`**:

- If the mods agree with you, then your flag will be marked as disputed (because you disagreed with the original flagger).
- If the mods disagree with you then it will be disputed as well! (because you disagreed with the mods)

Weird stuff.